How to start a ftp/ssh server on android though adb without root
Is it possible to start a ftp server or SSHD (SSH server) on android though ADB without root, then I can use WinSCP to access files on android from PC?
Currently I use some apps on android as a FTP server, but this needs operations on the phone, I wish to find a way only by PC CLI method (then for my scripts).

Should be possible with Termux (of course of on a standard port <1024 - as Android bases on Linux those ports can only be used with root permissions). If there is no other way you can make the SSH server start when termux starts - and app starting via adb is definitely always possible. Also the SSH server provided by Termux is usually better maintained that those included in apps.
